# Publishing a Message using AMQP Connector on MuleSoft ESB with TTY Extension

Tags: rabbitmq, mule, esb, anypoint-studio

Using MuleSoft ESB, how can I publish a message to rabbitMQ using the AMQP connector from AnyPoint studio that will expire.

```
<amqp:inbound-endpoint queueName="reusableQueue" 
exchangeType="direct" 
exchangeDurable="true" 
queueDurable="true" 
responseTimeout="10000"  
connector-ref="amqpConnector" 
doc:name="AMQP-0-9"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Exchange and Queue Declaration Arguments](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule-transport-amqp/blob/1d8475a34392a7d96a8c4a9bd28cc1b6f5134a9a/GUIDE.md#exchange-and-queue-declaration-arguments) section of the transport user guide explains how extra arguments can be configured on the endpoint.

The example below shows how this feature allows using the RabbitMQ DLQ extension, so you can use it similarly to leverage the [RabbitMQ TTL extension](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html).

```
<amqp:endpoint name="amqpEndpointWithArguments" exchangeName="target-exchange"
    exchangeType="fanout" exchangeDurable="true" exchangeAutoDelete="false"
    queueName="target-queue" queueDurable="true" queueAutoDelete="false"
    queueExclusive="true" routingKey="a.b.c">
    <properties>
        <spring:entry key="amqp-exchange.alternate-exchange"
            value="some-exchange" />
        <spring:entry key="amqp-queue.x-dead-letter-exchange"
            value="some-queue" />
    </properties>
</amqp:endpoint>
```